# Stop dynamic actions running on validation error?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have an Oracle APEX page that has a dynamic action which hides some fields at page load time, that are then made visible via other dynamic actions as the user interacts with fields on the page.

If the user submits the page with validation errors, the page reloads and it appears the dynamic action is being executed again and fields which have been filled in and should now be visible are being hidden again.

I'm wondering if I can make the page load dynamic action conditional so that it executes only when the page is not being rendered as a result of a validation error?

Many thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears I've found the solution.

One of the conditions available for whether the dynamic action gets executed is "No Inline Validation Errors Displayed".

Selecting this for the dynamic action that hides controls at page load effectively forces it not to run when validation errors are encountered.

Thanks to anyone who gave this some thought! Also, if you have any other helpful hints on effective validation with dynamic actions, I would be very interested in seeing them.